# Sending SIGINT (Ctrl-C) to program running in Eclipse Console

Tags: python, eclipse, twisted, sigint

I have setup a run configuration in Eclipse and need to send SIGINT (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) to the program. There is cleanup code in the program that runs after SIGINT, so pressing Eclipse's "Terminate" buttons won't work (they send SIGKILL I think). Typing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> into the Console also doesn't work.

How do I send SIGINT to a process running inside an Eclipse Console?

(FWIW I am running a Twisted daemon and need Twisted to shutdown correctly, which only occurs on SIGINT)

Answer (score 9):

If you can determine the process with a utility such as ps, you can use kill to send it a SIGINT. The program will likely be a child process of eclipse.

```
kill -s INT <pid>
```

Comment: Right now I use `kill -INT \`pgrep python\`` so I don't have to muck around finding pids, but even that is a bit cumbersome for rapid code/debug cycles.

Comment: You can shorten that to `pkill -INT python`, if you don't mind all python processes being killed.

Comment: So the point of the question is that kill+pgrep or pkill are blunt instruments (and there are in fact other python processes running that will get clobbered). I'm hoping for a more fine-grained approach, and CTRL-C via Eclipse seems like it should be possible.

Comment: I understand I am not directly solving your problem, but you can use pkill -f, along with stricter matching to ensure that SIGINT is only sent to the script you want.

Comment: Uri: Well, SIGINT is a UNIX signal.

Answer (score 2):

You can send the command via one line:

```
 kill -SIGINT $(ps aux | grep ProgrammName | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
```

Get the process id and than send the sigint signal

Comment: Shorter: `pkill -SIGINT -f ProgrammName`

Answer (score 0):

That still seems to be an open issue:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=38016

Just for the sake of completeness: If you came here to find a way to terminate a read line from `System.in`,
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> worked for me (on Windows).

Comment: Are you really talking about the _eclipse_ console? I can't confirm that for my Windows system: when hitting _Ctrl_ + _Z_ in the console view nothing happens.

Comment: Maybe I configured my runtime differently back then: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=38016#c1

Comment: The mentioned comment talks about _Ctrl_ + _C_ and even that one was not available since 2006, see [comment 11](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=38016#c11)

Comment: Let me try to reconstruct this: I think back then, I needed a way to terminate a read line from System.in. That's indeed a different problem, which was solved by pressing Ctrl + Z (EOF). It was mentioned in a comment by Bizmarck on jordanm's answer. Sorry for the confusion. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

in some versions, you can do the following.

In the Debug perspective, you can open a view called "Signals"
(Window/Show View/Signals" or Left-Bottom Icon).

You will get a list of all supported signals. Right-click and "Resume
with Signal" will give you the result you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making an answer out of a modification of [Artur Czajka's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814383/sending-sigint-ctrl-c-to-program-running-in-eclipse-console/65906715#comment49135643_28624925).

You can use `pkill -SIGINT -f ProgramName`. Explanation: `pkill` is similar to `killall`, `-SIGINT` states the signal to be used, `-f` makes it work better in this case (it will look through arguments and stuff instead of just the command name), and `ProgramName` is the target for pkill.