# Eclipse for C/C++ Developers and Ctrl+C

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, signals, sigint

I use Eclipse for C/C++ Developers version in order to write a code that has to respond to Ctrl+C click by sending the signal SIGINT. However, when I run my code from the console I find out that it doesn't respond to Ctrl+C at all. I diabled the functionality of Ctrl+C as a keymap for copy, and it still doesn't solve the problem. 
Do you know what I can do to solve it?

A Code example:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>


static void sig_int(int num) {
    printf("\nerror\n");
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) { //7

    sigset_t    zeromask;

    if (signal(SIGINT, sig_int) == SIG_ERR)
                    fprintf(stderr,"signal(SIGINT) error");

    printf("Hello\n");

    if (sigsuspend(&zeromask) != -1)
        fprintf(stderr,"sigsuspend error");

}
```

If you run this code from Linux terminal, when you click "Ctrl+C", you'll get an "error" output. However, of you run it from Eclipse console, nothing will happen. Eclipse console doesn't treat Ctrl+C as keyboard interrupt.

Comment: Post some code please, unless you're saying that it works from the terminal but not from eclise's console.

Comment: I edited my post and added some code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814383/sending-sigint-ctrl-c-to-program-running-in-eclipse-console
https://stackoverflow.com/search

Comment: @Rei, sorry, it still didn't help me. I couldn't find the pid of Eclipse. I tried to type in terminal 'ps' and 'jobs' and I didn't get anything referencing the Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that gdb is catching the SIGINT signal and not passing it on.

If you go to the gdb console (the one with the gdb version; not the one labeled "traces") and enter "info signals" you'll see a list like the following:

```
info signals
Signal        Stop  Print   Pass to program Description

SIGHUP        Yes   Yes Yes     Hangup
SIGINT        Yes   Yes No      Interrupt
SIGQUIT       Yes   Yes Yes     Quit
SIGILL        Yes   Yes Yes     Illegal instruction
```

Note that Pass for SIGINT is set to NO.

enter: handle SIGINT pass

SIGINT is also used by gdb so it may ask if you are really sure.

**EDIT**:

When I tried a simple program from Eclipse, the program is not receiving the SIGINT until the program has been paused. This may be a problem with Eclipse. When running directly from gdb, the program works as expected.